# How to navigate between points on flot chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I would like to build some sort of forward/back pager that will navigate between the points on my chart, highlighting the current point.

The closest example I've seen is something similar to the news legend on google finance charts, https://www.google.ca/finance?q=goog&ei=AD6dUvjOLMi0iAL9Uw

(you can click each news article/event and it will jump in the graph to the relevant point in time on the graph)

Can this be done with Flot and any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to just highlight a point or actually "scroll" the graph to a previous point in time?

Comment: Both would be preferable, but only highlight would be doable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a real quick example to demonstrate one approach to this problem.  On previous/next button clicks it highlights the previous/next point in the series and adjusts the xaxis so that the hightlighted point stays centered on the screen.

```
var highlightPoint = 15; // our first highlight
var xmin = 10, xmax = 20; // some arbitrary slice of series

var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1 ], //initial plot call
           {
               xaxis:{min: xmin, max: xmax}
           }); 
plot.highlight(0,highlightPoint); // initial highlight

$('#prevPoint').click(function(){
    plot.unhighlight(0,highlightPoint); // unhighlight previous selection
    highlightPoint -= 1; // move to left
    xmin = highlightPoint - 5; // adjust xaxis
    xmax = highlightPoint + 5;
    plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = xmin; // set xaxis into options
    plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].max = xmax;
    plot.setupGrid(); // refresh chart with new xaxis
    plot.draw();  // redraw
    plot.highlight(0,highlightPoint); //highlight new point
});
```

Makes more sense to look at the [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fKLcD/).